# Is it possible to install Headless Chrome without X11 dependencies?

Tags: google-chrome, headless, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I wonder if is it possible to somehow install [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) without X11 dependencies, e.g. on a VM or in a Docker container? Currently when I install it from the [Chrome repo](https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-in-debian-ubuntu-linux-mint/) it downloads lots of useless stuff as dependencies. It takes a long time to build a Docker container and it also requires additional space.

Comment: @virtualxtc Yes, that question is a duplicate of this one :-)